# Concatenate two properties in EF to populate a ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, entity-framework

Im developing a new WinForms Project using the Entity Framework, C# and .NET 4.5. In my database I have a table 'Teacher' with two columns 'FirstName' and 'LastName'. How could I populate a ComboBox control with a value made by these two properties?

The scenario:

```
private List<Teacher> ShowTeacher(String teacherID) 
{
   List<Teacher> teachers = (from teacher in context.Teacher 
                            select teacher).Where(t => t.UserID == teacherID).ToList();
   return teachers;  
}
```

And the code snippet in ComboBox:

```
cmbTeacher.DataSource = ShowTeacher(teacherID);
cmbTeacher.DisplayMember = ""; //here should be placed the string "FisrtName"+"LastName"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to include a fullname value on your datasource

```
List<Teacher> teachers = (from teacher in context.Teacher 
                          let FullName = teacher.FirstName + " " + teacher.LastName
                          select teacher).Where(t => t.UserID == teacherID).ToList();

cmbTeacher.DataSource = ShowTeacher(teacherID);
cmbTeacher.DisplayMember = "FullName";
```

---

```
class Teacher 
{
    public string FirstName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return LastName + " " + FirstName;
        }
    }

    public Teacher(string firstname, string lastname)
    {
        FirstName = firstname;
        LastName = lastname;
    }
}
```

Comment: But t is defined in the lambda expression, did you mean teachers.FirstName + " " teachers.LastName instead t.FirstName ...?

Comment: yes I fixed this already, refresh the page

Comment: I have to add the property FullName in Teacher class? Because it isn't shown properly. Thanks in advance

Comment: @MarioRodz yes exactly, see my edit for an example